# how to convert the date format while storing in phpmyadmin from the page

Tags: php, date, phpmyadmin, datepicker

How to change the normal input date format **dd-mm-yyyy** in the webpage to **yyyy-mm-dd** while storing in the php my admins

Comment: Did you tried anything with `date` function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can convert the date with strtotime();

```
  $dateToday = date("d-m-Y");
    $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateToday));
```

And then you can store data to your database.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can use [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime), I much prefer [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object.

```
//The second parameter being the string from the database.
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '27-10-2014');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```